# Create array elements by using variable variables with array elements in the variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I hardly understand my own topic, so let's start with an example:

```
$test = array("a","b","c");

$treevar = "test";

${$treevar}['k'] = array(1,2,3);  # Works

$letter = "l";
${$treevar[$letter]} = array(1,2,3);  # Gives error

$treevar = "test['m']";
${$treevar} = array(1,2,3);  # Does nothing (visible)

$treevar = 'test["n"]';
${$treevar} = array(1,2,3);  # Does nothing (visible)

$test["o"] = array(1,2,3);  # Works

print_r($test);
```

gives

```
Warning:  Illegal string offset 'l' in /home/backiiq199/domains/mvantloo.nl/public_html/kb/index_dropbox.php on line 17

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [k] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [o] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

What I eventually want is to build an `<UL>/<LI>` tree from an directory tree including folders and files.
As step in the middle, I want to build an multi-level array, so I can sort and filter and all those kind of fun, then transform the array to `<UL>/<LI>` structure.

To create the array I want that something like this would work (while it doesn't):

```
$treevar = "tree['level1']['level2']['level3']";
${$treevar} = array(1,2,3);
```

So where I first build the entire variable including all array elements, then create the variable variable.

The main reason is because the order of files and folders is chaotic, so I need to be able to add all missing parts of the tree. This I want to build by looping through the path structure.

I hope I'm a bit clear. Also other ideas are welcome of course.

Comment: I'd say pretty much any solution using variable variables is a bad idea (confusing, hard to read and maintain) and can most likely be done better and more efficiently using arrays or simple structures. Can you clarify what your actual goal is, and provide input/output samples?

Comment: @Jeto thank you for your answer, the actual goal is in my post and I want to build the array by temporary using variable variables.

Comment: Your post should be edited to showcase what you'd like to generate in the end. Like provide a sample directory structure and what HTML result you'd want from that.

Comment: @Jeto, thank you for your opinion, but I prefer an answer on this particular part of the solution, as it might be also useful in other situations. And there is also no fun if somebody just gives all code from dir structure to ul-li structure....

Comment: You won't be able to make us of variable variables with strings such as `"test['m']"` unless you either A) parse them using some kind of regex or B) `eval` them, both of which would be either ugly or massively frown upon.